# Change caption delimiter of specific figure in memoir

Tags: captions, memoir

Is there a way to change the caption delimiter of a single float using `memoir`?

For example, I have "Figure X: aaaaaa" and want to obtain "Figure X - aaaa".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by **specific caption delimiter**.

But you can try

```
\captiondelim{ -- }
```